# Cómo agrupar diferentes resultados de diferentes tablas una misma tabla y en una sola fila?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Le he dado vueltas y vueltas y no logro resolver este caso.

Quiero obtener entradas, salidas y una diferencia de insumos en una sola tabla de un rango de fecha en específico. Las consultas por separado serían las siguientes:

**Entradas:**

```
select m.idinsumo,i.descripcion,sum(cantidad) [total entradas] from movsinv m
left join conceptos c on c.idconcepto = m.idconcepto
left join insumos i on i.idinsumo=m.idinsumo
where c.tipo = 1 and m.fecha between '01-01-2020 7:00:00' and '02-08-2021 23:59:59'
group by m.idinsumo,i.descripcion
order by m.idinsumo
```

**Salidas:**

```
    select count(m.idinsumo)rep,m.idinsumo,i.descripcion,sum(cantidad)*-1 [total salidas] from movsinv m
left join conceptos c on c.idconcepto = m.idconcepto
left join insumos i on i.idinsumo=m.idinsumo
where c.tipo = 2 and m.fecha between '01-01-2020 7:00:00' and '02-08-2021 23:59:59'
group by m.idinsumo,i.descripcion
order by m.idinsumo
```

**Resultados de cada una:**

**ENTRADAS:**

```
001001          INS ACEITE VEGETAL  1.0000
001002          INS SAL REFINADA 1 KG   1.0056
001003          INS HARINA DE TRIGO 1 KG    1.0000
001004          INS SALSA MAGGI 1.0000
001005          INS SALSA INGLESA   1.0000
```

**Salidas:**

```
001002  INS SAL REFINADA 1 KG   0.0056
001008  INS CATSUP  0.0238
001044  INS IMP EDAMAME GREEND LANDA BOLSA  453 GR  0.1111
001065  INS IMP SALSA DE SOYA KIKKOMAN 18.9 LT  0.0188
001071  INS IMP MIRIN TAKARA SASONADOR 19 LT    0.0125
```

**Resultado esperado:**

```
id       nombre                 Entradas Salidas Existencia 
001001   INS ACEITE VEGETAL     1.0000    0       1.0000
001002   INS SAL REFINADA 1 KG  1.0056   0.0056   0.9944
001003   INS HARINA DE TRIGO    1.0000    0       1.0000
```

**El código que estoy usando:**

```
select m.idinsumo,i.descripcion
       ,(select sum(isnull(cantidad,0)) where c.tipo = 1) [total entradas]
       ,(select sum(isnull(cantidad *-1,0)) where c.tipo = 2) [total salidas]
       ,(select sum(isnull(cantidad,0)) where c.tipo = 1)-(select sum(isnull(cantidad *-1,0)) where c.tipo = 2) [Existencia teorica]
        from movsinv m
left join insumos i on i.idinsumo=m.idinsumo
left join conceptos c on c.idconcepto = m.idconcepto

where  m.fecha between '01-01-2020' and '02-08-2021'
group by m.idinsumo,i.descripcion,c.tipo,m.fecha
order by m.idinsumo
```

**Los resultados que obtengo:**

```
id       Nombre                 Entradas Salidas Existencia
001001   INS ACEITE VEGETAL     1.0000    NULL     NULL
001002   INS SAL REFINADA 1 KG  1.0056    NULL     NULL
001002   INS SAL REFINADA 1 KG  NULL     0.0056    NULL
001003   INS HARINA DE TRIGO    1.0000    NULL     NULL
001004   INS SALSA MAGGI        1.0000    NULL     NULL
001005   INS SALSA INGLESA      1.0000    NULL     NULL
```

Qué estoy haciendo mal?
Qué se les ocurre que pueda hacer?
Estoy usando sql.

**Les agradeceré infinitamente su ayuda.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta construcción `select sum(isnull(cantidad,0)) where c.tipo = 1` sin un `from` no debería funcionar, pero de todas formas, entiendo que lo que estas queriendo es realizar una suma condicional

```
select m.idinsumo,
       i.descripcion,
       sum(case when c.tipo = 1 then cantidad else 0 end)           [total entradas],
       sum(case when c.tipo = 2 then cantidad * -1 else 0 end       [total salidas],
       sum(case when c.tipo = 2 then cantidad * -1 else cantidad end) [total]
       from movsinv m
       left join conceptos c 
            on c.idconcepto = m.idconcepto
       left join insumos i 
            on i.idinsumo=m.idinsumo
       where c.tipo in (1, 2)
             and m.fecha between '01-01-2020 7:00:00' and '02-08-2021 23:59:59'
       group by m.idinsumo,i.descripcion
       order by m.idinsumo
```

La estructura es simple `case when <condicion> then <valor1> else <valor2> end`, en tu caso cuando `tipo = 2` la idea es siempre restar `cantidad`

Comment: NO LO PUEDO CREER!!!! Mil gracias!!!!! Me sirvió a la perfección, en la línea del total lo cambié para que me restara, estaba sumando. Aún no logro entender cómo es posible sin usar una operación para restar, pero WOW!!! La línea la dejé así: sum(case when c.tipo = 1 then cantidad else cantidad end) [total]

Comment: Ah, las salidas ya están en negativo.. Entonces simplemente `sum(cantidad)`